# Unit test function returning function in F#

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I have written the following function in F# which, given two points, returns a function representing the line which passes throught the two points:

```
let getFunction (point1:float*float) (point2:float*float) =
    let x1 = fst point1
    let y1 = snd point1
    let x2 = fst point2
    let y2 = snd point2
    let m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    let n = y1-x1*m
    fun x -> m*x+n
```

I would like to unit test this function, but I haven't find how to do it, since I can't use a function in a equality assertion. I have thought about generating a secuence of random points and testing the application of the function against the expected result for each point, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: you can always test `getFunction pt1 pt2 t` instead of just `getFunction pt1 pt2` - I can already see a few obvious candidates ... also you might find fscheck interesting

Comment: btw you can get `x1`,`x2`, ... right in there by doing `let getFunction (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = ...` which would make your function a lot shorter and easier to read

Comment: if you need the float just do `getFunction (x1:float,y1) (x2,y2) =` F# will figure out the rest

Comment: This is an off the deep end answer. What you really have is a math formula and you want to make sure its correct. When you come from OO to functional you often hear, take off you OO hat and put on your functional hat. Here you need to take off your programming hat and put on your math hat. Don't test the equation, prove it. Use [F*](https://www.fstar-lang.org/).

Comment: @GuyCoder what do you want to proof here? That's the definition of a line or do you want to do euclids elements in F*? ;)

Comment: @Carsten  I know he won't move the code to F*, but in thinking about he should realize that he needs to cover values such as [NaN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.nan(v=vs.110).aspx) If he did move the code to F* and then had that generate the F#, it would show him where the holes are in his code. F# functions are not math, and that gets lots of code into trouble. The equations has boundaries in F# which don't exist in Euclidian math.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a property-based testing approach (see http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/pbt/ for an excellent introduction).

You presumably want to check that, for any inputs (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), that the resulting function satisfies the following properties:

- f(x1) = y1
- f(x2) = y2
- f is linear

If the function satisifies these, it must be correct.

You can check the first two easily.  For the final property, you can pick some random x values to test.

Repeat for a selection of inputs, and you're done.  As Carsten mentions, FsCheck can be used to automate testing these properties using a large number of randomly generated test cases.